# How to access SQL Server 2008 from Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm using WATIR and Ruby 1.9.3 to test web applications and I need to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (Windows 7 64-bit). I already installed "DBI and DBD-ODBC" gems. I have also installed the ODBC Data Source, which I named 'BUILD'.  I was following the next steps, but unfortunately I'm getting a syntax error message. This is what I tried:

```
require 'dbi'
conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:BUILD', 'username', 'password')conn.connected?
```

---

Which gives me this error message:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):2: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end
...'username', 'password')conn.connected?
...                           ^
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

---

I honestly don't know what I'm doing wrong. I searched online for a solution, but apparently I couldn't find any answer that it can help me. I'll appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: What's going on with "conn" before ".connected?" ?

Comment: I edited the question - I hope the missing (?) newline in line 2+3 was not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a syntax error in this part:

`conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:BUILD', 'username', 'password')`**conn**`.connected?`

Try running this instead:

```
conn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:BUILD', 'username', 'password') #==> sets up the connection

conn.connected?  #==>  true if it is working
```

You had a method call followed immediately by a variable which is why your compiler is complaining that you never ended the method before you called `conn` again.

Comment: This sounds like a totally different issue.  If you are still struggling with it you should open up a new thread.  To get you started I would check out http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37103 .

Answer (score 1):

For easy access to a SQL Server you should have a look at TinyTds
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds